# Get date inside jquery datepicker with not-ISO date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, datepicker

I'm using jQuery datepicker to set the limit in a time series made with Highcharts for a personal project.

My date format is dd/mm/yyyy.

Following code works for sure till some weeks ago

```
onSelect: function () {
 var minTime = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(0)').datepicker("getDate").getTime();
 var maxTime = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(1)').datepicker("getDate").getTime();
}
```

But now I get following error:
"The specified value "03/02/2021" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Searching I've understood that it depends on the fact that I'm using a format different from the ISO.

How I can fix this issue maintaining my date format?

Bonus question:
What could be changed from the last time that I've checked my site?

Thank you all

Comment: *what could be changed* - depends on how you host your site and how you include libraries.  If you include "latest" and not a specific version, then maybe the library has changed.   If you're on a "framework" host, maybe they've changed the version.  Maybe the webserver host has changed locale.  Maybe the webserver software has been reconfigured.

Comment: Hello, I've supposed something similar, but if I look at my included library they refer to a specific version <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>. How can be that they changed?

Comment: It's unlikely to be jquery that causing the issue

Comment: Could be the Highcharts library? Actually I see that for it I'm not referring to a specific version, but to a generic https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js

Comment: The Highcharts library had an update on 2021-02-02, but you should use the particular version of the library for which you have purchased a license, not the generic one.